# Sync POSTGRES Database

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I have 2 postgres database servers one on-premise server and one cloud server both ubuntu . I need to synchronize live  between those 2 servers to keep data up-to-date .

What is the best way to make such thing done ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html

Comment: There is nothing in PostgreSQL that supports this, if you want to write to both databases.